# get kmls from iphone to pc

Tags: iphone

I have written an app that produces a kml files, how do I get them off an iphone on to a pc?

I am an android developer so I was a bit shock that the phone did not load as a flash drive when I plugged it in to the computer.

for some reason I cant get it to sync with itunes?

is this me or a more wide spread problem

Comment: [This is what I remembered while reading "I can't get it to sink with iTunes"...](http://cheezburger.com/4583078144)

Comment: you haven't really helped me with my problem, but you have made me smile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding "application does sync with itunes"  Value YES in the application plist.

this means when the user plugs the phone in to their computer they can access all the files generated by the app